# Управление статическими ресурсами Embedded jetty

Tags: java, jetty

Есть небольшой встроенный  сервер jetty

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SessionsServlet(accountService)), "/handle");

ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
resource_handler.setResourceBase("public_html");

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{resource_handler, context});

Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setHandler(handlers);
server.start();
```

Как в response отдать html страницу?

в папке  `public_html`  файл `index.html`
который посылает `post` запрос на сервлет (`/handle`) там я хочу в `response` отдать другую  html страницу которая находится например в   `public_html/register/register.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сервлете вы можете сделать forward на вашу страницу:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("register/register.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

или можете вернуть редирект на нее же (при этом у пользователя в браузере изменится адрес):

```
response.sendRedirect("register/register.html");
```